# How to sort different type numbers which with are in text file to textbox in descending?

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, sorting, system.io.file

It should let me choose a text file from my computer. There will be numbers in this text file. These numbers will be separated by “white-space” characters (hint: make sure you consider ALL of the white-space characters otherwise your program will probably fail). Decimal digits of decimal numbers will be separated by commas. The amount of numbers in the text file is uncertain. When I select the file and click on the button, I should see all the numbers in the text file sorted in the order from BIG to SMALL.

The content of a sample text file looks like this:

```
56   45 6 2 789
9 349   -87
11
4,34   -198,456
65
9,85      45
-1
99,456
877 56     34  4
```

I work on Visual Studio 2017.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace TestUygulamasi {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //get file and paste to testbox
        {
            Stream myStream = null;
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                try {
                    if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null) {
                        using (myStream) {
                            textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: File has not read. Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Sorting Button
        {
            string numbers = textBox1.Text;
            string[] arr;
            arr = numbers.Split(' ');
            Array.Sort(arr);

            string sorting = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i) {
                sorting = sorting + arr[i] + "\n";
                //sorting = arr[i] + "\n";
            }

            textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(sorting);
            //listBox1.Items.Add("\n" + sorting + "\n");
            //MessageBox.Show(sorting);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't sort the numbers in descendly.

Comment: Yes, they are numbers. "," define it is a decimal number. 99,456 is lower than 100. Just I need to remove white spaces and put them to array. Then I sort them in descendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer is this. I did not write this code. Person who wrote the code has deleted the code and his/her comments. Why he/she did it? I dont know. I hope he/she answer again under this question. I am new in the website so I could not vote up his/her answer. Thank you secret hero who I lost.

```
        List<decimal> nums = new List<decimal>();
        for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Lines.Count(); ++i)
        {
            string[] line = textBox1.Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ' ' },
                                                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string s in line)
            {
                nums.Add(decimal.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Number, new CultureInfo("tr-TR")));
            }
        }

        foreach (decimal d in nums.OrderByDescending(x => x))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(d.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq for the purpose.

```
var str = textBox1.Text;
var currentCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
currentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
currentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";

var numbers = str.Split(new string[] { " ",Environment.NewLine },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                     .Select(num=> decimal.Parse(num,currentCulture))
                     .OrderBy(num=>num);
textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,numbers);
```